# AJAX return data but got error message

Tags: ajax

I have used ajax to request data to php and it returns data in success block. but also it got an error in error block when onload.

```
$.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: actUrl,
        data: params,
        success: function(dat){
            console.log(dat);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error){
            alert("Error!" + xhr.status);
        },
        statusCode: {
          404: function() {
             alert( "page not found" );
          }
        }
```

Any comments would be appreciated :)

Comment: it shows xhr.status = 0

Comment: Could you post the backend method? What are you passing back and forth? What is the expected outcome?